# Authentication for GitLab to download a file with HTTPS

Tags: python, https, python-requests, gitlab

I created a private token on GitLab. I'm trying to download a file directly from my repository with HTTPS.

```
response = requests.get(
        [url],
        allow_redirects=True,
        headers={
            'PRIVATE-TOKEN': [token]
        })
    response.raise_for_status()
```

However, I'm getting:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Temporarily Unavailable for url: https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in
```

Comment: A 503 usually indicated a temporary server failure. You should try later.

Comment: @KlausD. Downloading it with Chrome works fine, and there is no message about server failure in `status.gitlab.com`.

Comment: The URL https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in is protected by CloudFlare and only works in web browsers. If you want to access GitLab from within python use the [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/).